# Adding color to a table cell using C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, html

I am creating a table and adding cells with contents through c sharp code. My code is as given below:

```
//creating the table
Table table1 = new Table();
table1.ID = "table1";
table1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Dashed;
table1.GridLines = GridLines.Both;
this.Controls.Add(table1);

//adding first row
TableRow row1 = new TableRow();

//adding first cell
TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();

//adding label
Label text1 = new Label();
text1.Text = "Sourav Ganguly";

cell1.Controls.Add(text1);
row1.Controls.Add(cell1);
table1.Controls.Add(row1);

//adding second cell
TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();

//adding label
Label text2 = new Label();
text2.Text = "Rahul Dravid";

cell2.Controls.Add(text2);
row1.Controls.Add(cell2);

//adding third cell
TableCell cell3 = new TableCell();

//adding label
Label text3 = new Label();
text3.Text = "Sachin Tendulkar";

cell3.Controls.Add(text3);
row1.Controls.Add(cell3);

//adding second row
TableRow row2=new TableRow();

//adding first cell
TableCell cell4 = new TableCell();

//adding label
Label text4 = new Label();
text4.Text = "Virender Shewag";

cell4.Controls.Add(text4);
row2.Controls.Add(cell4);
table1.Controls.Add(row2);

//adding second cell
TableCell cell5 = new TableCell();

//adding label
Label text5 = new Label();
text5.Text = "MS Dhoni";

cell5.Controls.Add(text5);
row2.Controls.Add(cell5);
table1.Controls.Add(row2);

//adding third cell
TableCell cell6 = new TableCell();

//adding label
Label text6 = new Label();
text6.Text = "Zaheer Khan";

cell6.Controls.Add(text6);
row2.Controls.Add(cell6);
table1.Controls.Add(row2);
```

I wish to add a background color for each cell. Is it possible to create anything like this? i.e in the first cell of the first row, I wish to add red color to only about 50% of the cell. I wish the cell to remain colorless (usual white color) for the remaining 50%. Similarly, for the second cell of the first row, I wish to add yellow color for 80% of the cell and I want the remaining 20% of the cell to be in default white color. Is is possible to achieve such a kind of functionality functionality using C#?

Comment: I just removed all of the extra blank lines from your code sample, but it's still quite large. Do we really need all of this code to explain your problem? (Not saying that we don't like code samples, but usually *short* and *complete* are the order of the day)

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly, but you can try to replicate the behavior by setting your Text property to the following:

```
<div style="width:100px;height:20px">
  <div style="background-color:red;width:80%;height:20px"/>
  <div style="float:left">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Of course, you'll want to replace the hard-coded dimensions and color.

Answer (score 0):

If your % are large, you can use colspan property for the cell and extend a particular colour to represent your graph.

Another option is to include a 1px image and then stretch it as required.

Something like:

```
TableCell cell= new TableCell();
Image img = new Image();
img.ImageUrl = "image url";
img.Width=80; //this can represent 80%
cell.Controls.Add(img);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is NOT optimized to render efficiently, but the principle works (CSS3):

```
//adding first row
TableRow row1 = new TableRow();

//adding first cell
TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();

//adding label
Label text1 = new Label();
text1.Text = "Sourav Ganguly";

//adding color
Integer perShaded = NUM;
cell1.Style = "background-image: url('color.gif'); background-size: " + perShaded + "% 100%;";

cell1.Controls.Add(text1);
row1.Controls.Add(cell1);
table1.Controls.Add(row1);
```